# How to post data as html formatted text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, react-hook-form

I have a front-end react application posting data to a server. Using CKEditor and React Hook Form. When I console.log the data prior to posting I get the ideal html formatted text ( `<p><strong>` ). However, when I check the data I see html entities ( `&lt;p>...s&lt;strong>` ). I'd like the server to receive the data as I see it in the front end, as html formatted text, so I can show it properly in other parts of the app. Here's the relevant code.

**CreateArticle.jsx**

```
...
const [ckData, setCkData] = useState(null)

...
const onSubmit = data => {
        // place tags into an array
        modifyTag(data);
        // retrive data from CKEditor, place into 'content'
        modifyContent(data)
        // 'content shows as html formatted text as intended
        console.log(data)
        // imported create article (POST) from axios.js
        createArticle(data)
            .then(res => {
                const id = res.data.data.id;
                setArticleId(id);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.error))
    }

...

   const modifyContent = (data) => {
        // React Hook Form troubles with CK and handleSubmit
        // manually replace content with ckData
        data.content = ckData
    }
...
<Controller
          as={<CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          onBlur={(event, editor) => {
          //save data to content variable
          const content = editor.getData();
          //save content to CkData hook
          setCkData(content)
          }}
        />}
   name="content" control={control}
 />
...
```

Is there a front end solution to this?

Comment: share the code `createArticle` method.

Comment: I just discovered why this is happening. I built in protection from injection attacks in my api, which is why it's converting the html formatted data into entities. I need to close this question and look up a way to convert the data to html formatted code.